# Xamarin NuGet Restore Failure. How to Change Packages to be Restored

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package-restore, gstreamer-sharp

So I've been playing with adding local references to some .dll files. At one point poking around with the Build I change it to support the .Net Standard Platform out of curiosity. This then un-included Xamarin.Forms as a reference, which I need. So I reverted back. However now when it attempts to restore Xamarin.Forms as a reference, it tries to find my included references and fails. Due to this failure it doesn't just not included my custom references, but it fails to include Xamarin.Forms.

```
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file /Users/*****/Projects/Goal_1.02/Goal_1.02/Goal_1.02.csproj.
Restoring packages for /Users/*****/Projects/Goal_1.02/Goal_1.02/project.json...
Restoring packages for .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111...
  GET https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.forms/index.json
  NotFound https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms' 295ms
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms''.
404 (Not Found)
  GET https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'
  NotFound https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms' 250ms
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms''.
404 (Not Found)
  GET https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.forms/index.json 313ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.forms/2.3.4.231/xamarin.forms.2.3.4.231.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.forms/2.3.4.231/xamarin.forms.2.3.4.231.nupkg 124ms
  NotFound https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms' 342ms
Failed to retrieve information about 'Xamarin.Forms' from remote source 'https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp.git/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms''.
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little stupid for posting this now. But for anyone who finds this looking for an answer. In Visual Studio for Mac you can find a sources tab under

Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Sources

In which you can choose for the troublesome source to not be included